# how to prove that a function is surjective - What's the topic?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am trying for days now, to find any ressources or tutorials on that but I can't figure out what is the topic of these problems:

$ f:R \rightarrow [-1,1], f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$ I shall say whether this is surjective,injective,bijective or not .

$ f(t) ={t² \choose t} , g(v,u)=u*v$ I shall say whether each and their compositions are injective, surjective, bijective

**I do not expect the solution ! **

I am just looking for the "topics" of these problems. Or any description of what I have to do at all. That is basically my problem ,I have not a clue what kind of work I shall do here or what kind of tools exist to do that.

So can anyone name the topics of these or give me a link where I can find a step by step instruction of what to do ?

*Of course I know what surjective, bijective, injective means, but I am clueless how to prove.

Comment: @admins: I am sorry , but the question includes why my tags might be totally wrong.

Comment: You are looking for standard one variable real analysis, that can be found in any introductory text. The second deals with two variables, which is often the content of the later chapters of an introductory text or second volume.

Comment: "that can be found in any introductory text" ; I have already found those and there are real clear definitions that I truly understand. But there's no description how to solve such questions.

Comment: The actual algebraic and other skills needed to prove these properties is typically covered in precalculus and beginning calculus courses, so I think what will help you better than searching among real analysis web pages and texts is to search among precalculus and calculus web pages. For example, try these searches and others very similar to them (e.g. also include the word "examples"): [precalclus + function + surjective](https://www.google.com/search?q=precalculus+function+surjective) AND [calculus + function + injective](https://www.google.com/search?q=calculus+function+injective).

Comment: @ Dave Renfro, I had to laugh with relief , because  after days of google and library research I only found crap. Now I typed that in (just a few different arrangements of words) I found useful information - thanks a lot for that one :) !

Comment: Incidentally, one useful strategy (when it works) is to observe that if a function is strictly monotone (means exactly one of either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing) on an interval, then the function is injective on that interval. Thus, if you can show the derivative is positive (or is negative) on an interval, then the function is injective on that interval, although in many situations it is easier to prove strictly monotone "from scratch" by using algebraic inequality methods.

Comment: @ Dave Renfro , can I show by the inverse function that a function is not injective? Or is this not enough?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "show by the inverse function that a function is injective"? If so, yes, but keep in mind that before you know there exists an inverse function, you have to know that the function is injective, so this seems somewhat analogous to showing a certain object is an apple by first showing that the object is a red apple.

Comment: No I mean it the other way around; If my inverse function collapses, because an item of the codomain is hit twice by different values of the domain - isn't it then that my original function must have been not injective ? Say I take the inverse of x^2 and I do not restrict the range - This would cause a collapse since this isn't a function then. Isn't that the proof for "this is NOT injective"?

Comment: I believe that your intended meaning is correct, but it would be more correct to describe this as examining the behavior of the [inverse relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_relation).

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a look at the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to [-1,1]$ defined by $$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}.$$

Recall that a function $f$ is injective if $$f(x) = f(y) \implies x =y.$$ With this in mind, we observe that $$\frac{x}{x^2+1} = \frac{y}{y^2+1} \implies xy^2 + x = x^2 y + y.$$ Solving this equation, we see that $y = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ or $y=x$ for $x=0$. So $f$ is not injective.

To see whether it is surjective, we need to determine whether for all $y \in [-1,1]$, there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$y = \frac{x}{x^2+1}.$$ If we take $y=1$, then \begin{eqnarray*}
1 = \frac{x}{x^2+1} & \implies & x^2 - x + 1 =0.
\end{eqnarray*} The discriminant of this function is negative, so there are no solutions. It follows that $f$ is not surjective, injective or bijective.

Comment: I do not exactly get what you have done at the injective observation, after you have eliminated the fraction.

Comment: >>> So is it basically about this ? : Injection; proof for f(y)=f(x), where x=y OR find an example where it does not work . And what about surjection? Is it also just to find an example? How do I proof if a function is surjective then?

Comment: @LurioTabasco Spend time really thinking about the definitions and thinking about the above argument I presented.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am a little confused about this since the function is injective at the given codomain as wolfram says: "https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+x%2F%28x^2%2B1%29+injective+on+[-1,1]"  or is it like that we try to proof a function in general?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have consulted some students of higher semester and discussed the question, so that is the suggestion I worked out then:

1. Sketch the graph - You will then have an idea whether you try to find a proof for or against injection/surjection
2. Assume you want to proof against injection/surjection just use the given function and put one of the values in that gives you the wanted falsification
3. Assume you want to proof for injection:
   a) If it is a simple linear equation, it is injective (in my class, we are allowed to stop here, better ask your teacher/professor)

   b) otherwise you can try to proof that it's a monotonic function

   c) If it is not a linear function, you can go for : If different inputs give you the same value: $f(a)=f(b)$ then it must be that a and b are the same values : $a=b$ you can do this by an equation.
4. Assume you want to proof for surjection: That is a little more tricky and needs your sketch; If you can see that it is surjective, you have to find a way how to show it.

   a) If your codomain is  really small you can try to show that there's no discontinuity

   b) If your codomain runs up to infinity you can try out the limit as x approaches infinity for your function

   c) there might be just some other arguments or simple proofs that depend on your individual problem

**Never forget that it is really important to have an eye on your function definition: "what's my domain? what's my codomain?"**